# Connecting Spring Boot REST API Backend to Angular Front End

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, back

I am trying to connect a Spring Boot Backend to an Angular front end. The application is supposed to ask the user for two numbers via two forms, and then adds them when they click the 'submit' button.

I have done both the front end and back end, but am having trouble integrating them both together. I have tried to make a UserService on the angular end to account for user interaction, but have been stuck on that. I have no idea what to put on the Spring Boot back end for the Controller, either. I've searched up several YouTube tutorials, but most of them are catered to the specific application the Youtuber is creating, and doesn't explain what each line of code does, so I can't take the code and edit it accordingly to my own project.

Answer (score 1):

Are you exposing any REST apis on your Spring back end project?
Your Angular front end project should use the Angular HTTPClient to make a call to any RESTful endpoint your Spring back end is exposing

https://angular.io/guide/http